# Setting events in Google tag manager without element IDs in HTML

Tags: html, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

In google tag manager, I am trying to setup analytics event on form submission. Ideally form id is required for configuration of a form submission event through GTM, but the HTML pages don't have any element IDs defined(no form id present).

Is there a work around to capture events without element IDs defined in HTML?

Comment: Well, there also form class, form target, or form url that you could try. Check this out, too: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/track-form-engagement-with-google-tag-manager/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the route you want to take. However, regardless of the route, you absolutely need something that identifies the form and/or the submission button. It doesn't need to be an ID, but it's ideal if there's a unique wrapper class or ID.

You could track clicks on the submission button, however, your numbers won't be entirely accurate. For example, if you have a required field on that form, and someone clicks the submit button, the form will not submit. However, you tag will fire regardless. That said, tracking clicks can be an easy solution, and will give you a good idea of how much interaction that your webform is driving.

To implement tracking on the submission button, add a new tag of type "Custom HTML". Insert the following:

```
<script>
  (function ($) {
    $(function () {
      $('#submit-btn').click(function() {
        dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'GAEvent', 
            'eventCat': 'Form Submissions', 
            'eventAction': 'Form Submission Action', 
            'eventLabel': 'Form Submissions Label',
            'gaNonInt': false
        });
      });
    });
  }(jQuery));
</script>
```

Basically, this function pushes data to GA whenever the HTML element associated with the "#submit-btn" ID (this can be a class or ID) is clicked. In my case, that ID was attached to the form `<button>` element.

You'd need to set up variables for event, eventCat, eventAction, etc. in order for this to work.

I only work with JQuery within GTM, but imagine there are alternative ways to track your form clicks. I'd be happy to explain my process in more detail, if you need further assistance. Otherwise, good luck!